# Annoying chatterbox

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there are word for an individual who seems incapable of stopping talking when his companions clearly prefer periods of silence?

Comment: If you could inform us with the specific reasons why [chatterbox](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Chatter-box), and [the best alternatives listed in a thesaurus are inadequate](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/chatterbox?s=t) for your intended use,  we might be able to help you find a better word, but otherwise synonym requests can be closed for being either unclear or answerable by commonly available resources. You also need to include an exemplary context that closely matches your intended use to ask [tag:single-word-requests] here.

Answer (score 0):

How about [*motormouth* (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/motormouth)?

- a person who talks quickly and continuously, often without considering what they are saying

Synonyms listed there include *gasbag* ("a person who talks too much" ) and *windbag* ("a person who talks too much about boring things")

Comment: These all lack the slight charm of *chatterbox* (as in Little Miss)

Answer (score 0):

In the case the person talks always about a particular topic, for example  sports, he or she is called a sports-nut.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little old fashioned but I like "prattler."